# How to know those that have logged-in or not logged-in within a set date using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this code in Laravel-5.8 to filter the users within a set date as shown below:

```
public function userReport(Request $request)
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;

    $users= User::where('hr_status', 0)->where('company_id', $userCompany)->orderBy('last_login_at', 'desc');
    
    $start_date = $request->start_date;
    $end_date = $request->end_date; 
    
    $render=[];
    
    if(isset($request->start_date) && isset($request->end_date))
    {
        $winners=$winners->whereBetween('last_login_at',[$start_date.' 00:00:00',$end_date.' 23:59:59']);
        $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
        $render['end_date']=$request->end_date;
    }elseif(isset($request->start_date))
    {
        $users=$users->where('last_login_at',$request->start_date);
        $userr['start_date']=$request->start_date;
    }
   
    $users= $users->paginate(15);
    $users= $users->appends($render);
    $data['users'] = $users;
     return view('report.userReport',$data);
}
```

The date for reference point is last_login_date

View

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    {{ Form::model(request(),['method'=>'get']) }}
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        {{ Form::date('start_date',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Date']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        {{ Form::date('end_date',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Date']) }}
    </div>          
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        {{ Form::submit('Search',['class'=>'btn btn-warning']) }}
         </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

How do I complete the code in the controller to know the:

1. users that have logged- withing the specified date
2. users that have not logged-in within specified date

Thanks

Comment: Did my solution solve your issue? If not, let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query on dates like so:

```
$periodEnd = Carbon::now();
$periodStart = Carbon::now()->subWeek();

$thisWeek = Model::whereDate('time_column', '>=', $periodStart)
                 ->whereDate('time_column', '<=', $periodEnd)
                 ->get();
```

In your case you can do something like this:

```
$users = User::$query();

// Assuming you are expecting dates in Y-m-d format
if (isset($request->start_date)) {
    $start_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->start_date);
    $users->whereDate('last_login_at', '>=', $start_date);
}

if ($request->end_date) {
    $end_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->end_date);
    $users->whereDate('last_login_at', '<=', $end_date)
}

$loggedIn = $users->get();

$notLoggedIn = User::whereNotIn('id', $loggedIn->pluck('id'))
                   ->get();
```